# How do I have two Flipbooks on a single page?

Tags: turnjs

I can't get two flipbooks working at the same time on the same page.

Is it possible to get both running on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a number to the #flipbook id.
e.a.: Use #flipbook1 for the first flipbook and #flipbook2 for the second one.
With this you can add as many flipbooks as you like on on one page.
In addition to this;
By storing your flibook data in an Array you can use a 'for loop' to initiate them.